# Laser activated switch using a photo-transistor

Tags: led, sensor, switches, light-sensor

I would like to make a laser activated switch using a photo-transistor or an LDR, by which I can switch off the lights in a room from a long distance. I just have to point the laser and it will detect my signal and the light must turn off.

Can anybody please help me with a circuit diagram?

Comment: Lots a ideas, but why don't you take a swing at it first and then we'll have some idea of your skill set.

Answer (score 1):

With help of Latching switch and LDR we can do that.

Latching Switch

[image: Latching Switch].

Load Circuit

[image: Load]

Replace Load with the circuit as shown above and push button (S1) with LDR.